# change contents of a file in previous commits to current data

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have ~50 commits in my local Git repository. I have made some changes to a particular file in current HEAD, and i would like to update those file changes to all the previous commits. Is it possible achieve this in git??

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The idea of git is to keep track of the change history.

Comment: @Fede - there are a few good reasons (and numerous not-so-good reasons) why someone might do this. I don't disagree with advising that anyone considering doing this should check and recheck their reasoning, but in the end, the question is what it is - if OP thinks their history is more valuable with a particular file replaced, it's not our project to argue about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Although the command in my original answer works, on reflection it may not be the best one to use in an index filter; added some comments about this

---

It is possible, but there is a cost.

What you are describing is a "history rewrite", which will change the commit ID of every commit.  If you alone use this repo, and you haven't been using the commit ID (SHA) values for anything (like documentation, or whatever), then that's probably fine.

If others also use the repo (or if you have multiple clones) you'll need to coordinate a cut-over.  Basically my advice would be to arrange for a time when all updates have been pushed to a common repo (probably origin), then discard all the clones, then do the rewrite and replace the origin, then re-clone.  Technically you don't have to do it that way, but see "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation (which actually applies to any history rewrite).

So if you decide to go ahead with the rewrite, the simplest way is probably to use `git filter-branch`.  (If certain assumptions about your repo are true, then a `rebase`-based approach could work; but `filter-branch` is more generally applicable.)

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git reset master -- file/to/be/rewritten' -- --all
```

This creates some "backup" refs which you'll want to remove once you've validated the result.

Note that I originally suggested

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git checkout master -- file/to/be/rewritten' -- --all
```

which also seems to work; but the `reset` command is more purely related to updating the index, so may be a better choice here.

Comment: By the way, if you have any commits where the only thing changed wrt the parent was the file you're replacing, then that commit will now match its parent exactly.  If you wish, you can remove such commits by including the `--prune-empty` option to `filter-branch`